# Distributed Version Control. - Git & Mercurial... multiple sites

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm looking for a best practice scenario on managing multiple "sites" in mercurial. Since I'm likely to have multiple sites in a web root, all of which are different - but somewhat similar (as they are 'customizations' of a root app)

Should I 
A) make a single repository of the wwwroot folder (catching all changes across all sites)
B) make EACH sits folder a different repository

this issue is that each site needs a distinct physical directory, due to vhost pointing for development, and a current need to have "some" physical file difference cross site.

What's the best practice here? I'm leaning towards separate repositories for each directory. which will make tracking any branching and merging for that ONE site cleaner....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your software is structured, and how independent the different sites are. The best situation is when you can use your core code like a library, which lives in its own directory, and there is no need in the different sites to change even a single file of core. Then you have the free choice if you want to develop the core along with the different sites in a single repo, or to seperate core from sites. When core and the different sites are dependent on each other, you very probably have to deal with all of them in a sigle repo.

Since in my experience development work better when the different parts are independend of each other I strongly recommend to bring the core stuff into something which can be included into the sites by a directory inclusion.

The next point is how are the different sites developed. If they share lots of code, they can be developed as different branches. But there are two disadvantages of this scheme:

- the different sites are normally not visible to the developer, since there is typically only one checked out
- The developer has to take great care where to create changes, so that only the wanted changes are going into other branches, not something which is special to a single branch only

You might consider to move common parts of different sites into core if they share lots of common code.

Another situation is if they all have nothing in common, since then things are much better. Then you need to decide if you want them to reside in different repos, or as different directories in a single repos. When these different sites are somehow related to each other (say that they are all of the same company), then it might be better to put them into a common repo, as different subdirectories. When they are unrelated to each other (every site belongs to a different customer, and changes on these sites are not created in synch to each other), than one repo per site is better.

When you have the one repo per site approach, it might also be good if you first create a template site, which includes the core component and basic configuration, and derive your site-repos as clones from this template. Then when you change something in the core which also affects the sites, you do these changes in the template, and merge these changes afterwards into the sites repos (you only need to take care to NOT do this change in one of the site-repos, since when you merge from sites to template you might get stuff from the specific site into the template, which you don't want to be in the template).

So I suggest

- develop core as a single independent product
- choose the correct development model for your sites

  - all in one repo, with branches, when there is much code-exchange is goin on between different sites
  - but better refactor the sites to not share code, since the branches approach has drawbacks
  - all in one repo, no branches but different folders, if there is no code exchange between different sites
  - one repo for each site if they are completely independent.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to try [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) with one repo. I.e

- you store "base" site in repository
- all site-specific changes separated into the set of MQ-patches (one? patch per site)
- you **can** create "push-only" repos in sites, add they to [paths] section of "working" repo and push changes or use export-copy technique

and after applying the site-patch to codebase you'll get ready to use code for *each and every* site